# I'm writing a test case in React related to authentication(using axios), But I am stuck because the test case is not passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, tdd

Existing code:
loginUser.js:

```
import { getUserDetails } from '../api/userDetails';
import { mapApiObjectToModel } from '../mapper/userProfileMapper';
import axios from 'axios';
export const getLoggedInUserDetails = async () => {
  axios
    .get('/api/getUserDetails')
    .then(response => {
      return mapApiObjectToModel(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error==', err);
    });
};
```

userProfileMapper.js:

```
export const mapApiObjectToModel = inputObj => {
  const outputObj = {};
  const authorizedRoles = ['Admin'];
  if (inputObj) {
    outputObj.fullName = '';
    if (inputObj.data) {
      outputObj.fullName = inputObj.data.data;
    }
    outputObj.role = 'Admin';
    outputObj.isAuthorized = authorizedRoles.includes(outputObj.role);
  }
  console.log('outputObj', outputObj);
  return outputObj;
};
```

loginUser.test.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import getLoggedInUserDetails from '../../action/loginUser';
jest.mock('axios');
describe('routes using memory router', () => {
  it('Get Admin message', async () => {
    const data = 'Admin';
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
    console.log(data);
    await expect(getLoggedInUserDetails()).resolves.toEqual(data);
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/api/getUserDetails');
  });

  it('fetches erroneously data from an API', async () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Network Error';
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage)));
    await expect(getLoggedInUserDetails()).rejects.toThrow(errorMessage);
  });
});
```

I'm really new to all these, so any assistance would be appreciated. Even any suggestions on TDD for userProfileMapper.js would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The `mapApiObjectToModel` returns an object like,

```
{
  role: 'ADMIN',
  isAuthorized: true
}
```

However, in your test, you are expecting it to be equal to a string 'Admin'

```
const data = 'Admin';
...
await expect(getLoggedInUserDetails()).resolves.toEqual(data); // Note that you have initialize data to 'Admin'
```

Try changing data to be an object, like,

```
const data = {
  role: 'Admin',
  isAuthorized: true
};
...
await expect(getLoggedInUserDetails()).resolves.toEqual(data);
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your respone. I know, getLoggedInUserDetails is not a function, but I'm wonder what to substitute in place of that since I'm getting the below error: 
  TypeError: (0 , _loginUser.default) is not a function

      16 |     axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
      17 |     console.log(data);
    > 18 |     await expect(getLoggedInUserDetails()).resolves.toEqual(data);
         |                  ^
      19 |     expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/api/getUserDetails');
      20 |   });
      21 |

Answer (score 0):

Updated: **loginUser.js**:

```
import { getUserDetails } from '../api/userDetails';
import { mapApiObjectToModel } from '../mapper/userProfileMapper';
import axios from 'axios';
export const getLoggedInUserDetails = () => {
  return axios
    .get('/api/getUserDetails')
    .then(response => {
      return mapApiObjectToModel(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error==', err);
      throw err;
    });
};
```

You function `getLoggedInUserDetails` had following issues,

1. You were not returning the promise from the function.
2. You don't need `async` here as you are accessing `expect(Promise).resolves` in your test file *loginUser.test.js:*.
3. You need to throw `err` from catch block, if you want to test the rejection of promise or remove the catch block.

I have updated following items to the function `getLoggedInUserDetails`,

1. removed the `async` from `export const getLoggedInUserDetails = async () => {`
2. returned promise from `axios.get('/api/getUserDetails')`
3. added `throw err` to catch block

You should not mix usage of `Promise.then` and `async/await` for more information on the difference between them check [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/async-await-vs-promises-4fe98d11038f) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)